# Complications with Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-lifecycle

I am using a ViewPager and have 3 Fragments in it.

I know that when the ViewPager loads for the first time it loads all the fragments by default ,

minimum is 3 fragments and viewpager executes all the lifecycle methods of fragments.

**Problems I noticed :**

- Whenever I swipe the viewpager the selected fragment doesn't call any of its  lifecycle methods again.
- Hence I cannot access the global variables directly.

  e.g: if I have a preference initialized in OnCreateView() I  am getting NPE when I try to access it from activity by initializing the instance of that fragment and calling a method in that fragment.
- Also not even onResume is getting called for any fragment after first loading.

**What I want to Know :**

- How can I access the views and preferences after I have already initialized them in onCreateView() ?
- But for the button which is initialized in onCreateView(), on click of it calls the web-services and works perfectly as I want .How ?

*I have stuck with these issues from the past 3 days and googled a lot but not found my answers.*

Any Help will be appreciated.

**Fragment Code :**

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dth, container, false);

   preferences= 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    editor = preferences.edit();


    editAmt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editAmt);
    browsplan = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.browsplan);


    Log.e("DTH onCreateView ",""+page);

    String fontpath = "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), 
    fontpath);

    editCustomerid.setTypeface(tf);
    editAmt.setTypeface(tf);

    token=preferences.getString("Token","-1");
    mobileNo=preferences.getString("userMobileNo","0");



    browsplan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          //new DTHOperator(getActivity()).execute();   HERE IT WORKS PROPERLY
        }
    });

    return v;
}

 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(isVisibleToUser && isResumed()){
        new DTHOperator(getActivity()).execute();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"setUserVisibleHint DTH  " 
       ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }

  public class DTHOperator extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {
    Context ctx;

    DTHOperator(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> telecomdata = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String result;
        Log.d("Register Activity Token", /*preferences.getString("Token", "")*/token);

        telecomdata.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobNo", /*preferences.getString("userMobileNo", "")*/mobileNo));
        telecomdata.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestDate", Utilities.getApiCallTimeFormat()));
        telecomdata.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reqFrom", "APP"));
        Log.v("PostParameters", "telecomdata" + telecomdata);
        if (Connectivity.checkNetwork(ctx)) {
            result = rechargeUrl.queryRESTurlONline(ctx, "/GetDTHOperatorsService", "post", telecomdata, GenericConstants.PiPay_root);
        } else {
            result = GenericConstants.NETWORKNOTFOUND;
            displayToast("The Internet Connection appears to be offline");
        }


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        MyProgress.show(ctx, "", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(GenericConstants.NETWORKNOTFOUND)) {
                    MyProgress.CancelDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,"The Internet Connection appears to be offline",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                String[] resArr = result.split("delimiter_");
                if (!resArr[0].equals("500")) {
                    MyProgress.CancelDialog();
                    Log.d("DTHOperator Response ::", result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                    jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("opName")) {
                            operator.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("opName"));

                            Log.d("", " Question size " + operator.size());
                        }
                    }

                    if(MyProgress.isShowingProgress())
                        MyProgress.CancelDialog();

                        editAmt.setText("2000");  // NPE HERE Also setting the value  

                } else {
                    MyProgress.CancelDialog();
                    displayToast("Failure");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            MyProgress.CancelDialog();
        }finally {
            if(MyProgress.isShowingProgress())
                MyProgress.CancelDialog();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Joyal I have posted my fragment code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep instances of `Fragments` which you use in your `ViewPager`. Here's an example:

In your `ViewPagerAdapter` define a `SparseArray` and override the methods like below:

```
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}
```

And add a `PageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Here's your fragment instance
        // You can access it's methods, variables, views etc.
        YourFragment fragment =(YourFragment)yourPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

I hope this'll help you. Good luck!

Edit:

You can define your Fragment's Views public or define a getter method for your view and access from your fragment instance such as:

```
public TextView mTextView;
```

or

```
private TextView mTextVieW;
public TextView getTextView(){
   return this.mTextView;
}
```

You can access it like below:

```
TextView textView = yourFragmentInstance.mTetxView;
```

or

```
TextView textview = yourFragmentInstance.getTextView();
```

Comment: Let me try your answer I will get back to you .

Comment: if you have problems about implementation let me know.

Comment: savepopulation I am able to get the reference of fragments but not able to access the views globally , you can see my code.

Comment: Define your views public or write a getter method which returns your view. i'll edit my code.

Comment: You are right bro , it was public that helped me..I dont believe i was stuck with this thing

Comment: no problem. can you accept my answer? thanks.

Comment: savepopulation Can you tell me why i was able to access the variables on Button Click. in onCreateView() ?

Comment: sorry i could not understand what you're asking. let's use chat instead of commenting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124507/discussion-between-ashish-shukla-and-savepopulation).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following override method

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

        }
    }
```

this will give you an option to call anything when the the user is currently viewing the fragment.

- Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible * to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment                  instance* state save and restore.

  - An app may set this to false to indicate that the fragment's UI is
  - scrolled out of visibility or is otherwise not directly visible to the user.
  - This may be used by the system to prioritize operations such as fragment lifecycle updates
  - or loader ordering behavior.
    *
  - @param isVisibleToUser true if this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user (default),
  - false if it is not.

Comment: I tried your method but when I access my Edittext which is initialized in onCreateView it gives me NPE .

Comment: Send me the fragment in which you got the null pointer exception.

Comment: Joyal I liked your method bcoz it can directly access the class when actually its in front. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my last project.  I like this approach too because I don't have to do anything weird.

Essentially, in my adapter for the viewpager I added a method to keep track of the fragment tags & the associated position.

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Map<Integer, String> tagMap = new HashMap<>(2); // matches tab count

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fMgr) {
        super(fMgr);
    }
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // Capturing the tag that is auto-generated
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment frag = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);

        tagMap.put(position, frag.getTag());

        return frag;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     *
     * @param position
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment frag = null;

        ...

        return frag;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of views available.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = null;

        ...

        return title;
    }
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    public String getFragmentTag(int position) {
        return tagMap.get(position);
    }
} // end of class TabAdapter
```

Then access within my activity (event methods) as:

```
String fragTag = tabAdapter.getFragmentTag(tabPosition);
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
```

Of course this means you have to keep a reference of the adapter in your containing activity.

From here my fragments will have simple callbacks and explicit methods to update whatever views I need to update.

Comment: zec I am able to get the reference of fragments but not able to access the views globally , you can see my code.